# Как можно объединить git - репозиторий r2 и r3 внутри r1 с коммитами и т.д.?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-branch

Структура папок:

```
r1 /
  .git
      r2/
         .git
          main.cpp
      r3/
         .git
          main1.cpp
```

Мне нужно объединить репозиторий r2 и r3 внутри r1 чтобы все коммити и истории перемешались

Я хочу, чтобы папки оставались на своих местах, а все истории и коммиты были объединены

точнее, здесь я клонировал репозиторий r2 и r3 внутри r1
, а затем опубликовал
Но потом не смог открыт репозиторию r2 и r3 внутри github
Там папка отображается, но открывается

Comment: [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая утилита [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), официально рекомендованная авторами git.

Позволяет переписать историю в репозитории по указанным правилам. В частности, можно перенести во всех коммитах все файлы из корня репозитория в подпапку.

Выполняете такое действие с репозиториями r2 и r3.

Далее у r1 подключаете и r2 и r3 как remote, делаете из обоих fetch, и межите их master'а в master r1.

Готово.

PS конкретные команды не привожу, так как в разных ОС (Win, Linux) они будут сильно отличаться мелкими деталями типа кавычек, слэшей и т.д.